# To remove the characters from a string if the even position of the string contains the vowel using C#

Tags: c#

To remove the characters from a string if the even position of the string contains the vowel using C#. Create a class with the name `RemoveVowelFromString`. Create a method with the named `GetString` to remove vowels from even places in the given string.

Return type of the method `GetString` should be `string`. Input parameters should be as per the details mentioned below.

```
Parameter1 name="input" type="string" 

<param name="input"></param><type>string</type> <returns>string</returns>
```

All the classes and methods should be declared as 'public'.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace RemoveVowels
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            RemoveVowelFromString obj = new RemoveVowelFromString();
            string ans = obj.GetString(x);

            Console.WriteLine(ans);
            Console.ReadKey();
public class RemoveVowelFromString
    {
        public string GetString(string input)
        {
            string str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'e' || input[i] == 'i' || input[i] == 'o'|| 
                        input[i] == 'u' || input[i] == 'A' || input[i] == 'E' || input[i] == 'I' 
                          || input[i] == 'O' || input[i] == 'U')

                     --------------;
                }
            }
            return str;

        }
    }
}
```

Help me to proceed further.

Comment: This is a console application, not an ASP.NET web application. Please do not tag ASP.NET when you're not using ASP.NET.

Comment: _"Help me to proceed further"_ - Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Llama inside the if condition , I need to remove the char which are equal to the vowels . I'm comparing each and every char , but I don't know how to do it. I mentioned as ----- in the code.

Comment: I'd suggest converting `input` to a `List<char>` (you can use `List<char> characters = input.ToList();`), then you can iterate through from the end of the string to the beginning (you're removing items, so you don't want to miss any by iterating beginning->end) and then you can remove them. Then you can make a new string from the remaining list using `new string(characters)`.

Comment: Replace -------- with `continue`. Add below your if {...} block `str += input [i];`

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace RemoveVowels
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = Console.ReadLine();
        RemoveVowelFromString obj = new RemoveVowelFromString();
        string ans = obj.GetString(x);

        Console.WriteLine(ans);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class RemoveVowelFromString
    {
        public string GetString(string input)
        {
            string str = input;
            string[] vowels = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U" };

            DataTable DT_Output = new DataTable();
            DT_Output.Clear();
            DT_Output.Columns.Add("RowID");
            DT_Output.Columns.Add("Char");
            DT_Output.Columns.Add("NewChar");

            int b = 1;
            foreach (char item in str)
            {
                DT_Output.Rows.Add(b, item.ToString(), String.Empty);
                b++;
            }

            foreach (DataRow item in DT_Output.Rows)
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(item[0]);
                string strChar = item[1].ToString();
                string newChar = String.Empty;

                if (rowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < vowels.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(strChar == vowels[i].ToString())
                        {
                            newChar = String.Empty;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newChar = strChar;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    newChar = strChar;
                }
                item["NewChar"] = newChar;
                item.EndEdit();
                DT_Output.AcceptChanges();
            }

            string strNew1 = String.Empty;
            foreach (var column in DT_Output.Columns)
            {
                DataColumn dc = column as DataColumn;
                strNew1 = string.Join("", DT_Output.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                                             .Select(r => r[dc]));
            }

            return strNew1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most ineffective way to accomplish the removal. Try again;)